# ajax img change

Tags: javascript, ajax, image

i have implemented a code that fetch *single image* from 1000+ images. The image has been changed using ajax call and downloading time of each image varies. How to make this image change with smooth transition from one another i.e ***without any*** ***flicker and ajax processing image***

Comment: are you preloading the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pre-select the images you are about to load and store it in a persistent array:

```
var image_paths = new Array();
/* fill image_paths */

window.preload_images = new Array();

for (var i in image_paths) {
    var image_src = image_paths[i];
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = image_src;
    preload_images.push(img);
}
```

This will tell the DOM to load the image into a JavaScript `Image` object but to not destroy it unless `preload_images` is unset.